# LINQ to entities compare DateTimeOffset's only date part

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I am trying to compare only date part of DateTimeOffset in Linq. But auto generated query still add timezone. I am using DbFuncation.TruncateTime but it is only truncate time part. Timezone part is still comparing. May I know how can I compare DateTimeOffset's DateTime part only.

```
query.Where(p =>
                 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.ETD) >= trimCriteriaDto.StartDate 
                 && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.ETD) <= trimCriteriaDto.EndDate);
```

Comment: does using the .net `.TruncateTime(p.ETD).Date()` function work?? likewise, `.StartDate.Date()` and `.EndDate.Date()`... just a thought

Comment: ETD is datetimeoffset in sql and if use like .net date p.ETD.DateTime, it gave me error because LINQ unsupported error..Thanks.